# Why is this MainActivity class code working?

Tags: java, android

I am writing tic tac toe game in which i am calling imageTapped when image is tapped to change its image to cross and then it calling aiturn to find valid move and change its image to circle. Now my question is how did calling non static method aiturn from non static method imageTapped works without creating its object.

```
package com.example.kapil.tictactoe;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GameLogic gameLogic;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    TextView label;

    public void imageTapped (View view) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
        label = findViewById(R.id.label);
        String pos = image.getTag().toString();

        //if button is already tapped
        if (! gameLogic.setImage(Integer.valueOf(pos)))
            return;
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);

        //return 1 for win 2 for draw otherwise 0
        int  win = gameLogic.logic();
        if (win == 1) {
            label.setText("You Win!!");
            gameLogic.gameOver();
            return;
        } else if (win == 2) {
            label.setText("Game Draws!!");
            return;
        }

        aiturn();

    }

    public void aiturn () {
        int move = gameLogic.aiMove();//return best move between 0 to 8

        int rowNum = move/3;
        int colNum = move%3;

        if (rowNum == 0) {
            linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.line1);
        } else if (rowNum == 1) {
            linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.line2);
        } else if (rowNum == 2) {
            linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.line3);
        }
        ((ImageView) linearLayout.getChildAt(colNum)).setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
        label = findViewById(R.id.label);

        //return 1 for win 2 for draw otherwise 0
        int win = gameLogic.logic();
        if (win == 1) {
            label.setText("AI wins!!");
            gameLogic.gameOver();
        } else if (win == 2) {
            label.setText("Game Draws!!");
        }
    }

    //if play again button is pressed
    public void Reset (View view) {
        gameLogic.reset();
        TextView label = findViewById(R.id.label);
        label.setText("");

        int ids[] = {R.id.line1,R.id.line2,R.id.line3};

        for (int k=0;k<ids.length;k++) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(ids[k]);
            for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                ((ImageView) linearLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gameLogic = new GameLogic();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus to send and receive events. When you want to call a method send an event and on receive of that event call the method from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now my question is how did calling non static method `aiturn` from non static method `imageTapped` works without creating its object.

Android apps are not launched using a `public static void main(...)` method like a classic Java app.

Instead, when your app is launched, the Android framework automatically creates instances of your app's Activity classes, and wires them up to the user interface (as per the XML file).

Then, when the user "taps", the framework calls the `imageTapped` method on the (existing)  activity object.  That then calls `aiturn` on the same object.

Or at least, I think that is the *intent* of the person who wrote that code.  In reality, the `imageTapped` method doesn't appear to be an API method in the superclass hierarchy of your `MainActivity` class.  So I *suspect* that it won't be called.

I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do, but maybe you should override `onTouchEvent(...)`

Answer (score 2):

This works because the Android framework creates the instances of Activities.